# Get invocation option(s) from within Makefile

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, compilation, gnu-make

I can invoke (GNU) make with the `-j` option, enabling multiple jobs to be run in parallel:

```
make -j
```

Is it possible from within the Makefile to determine whether or not make was invoked with this option? I have tried looking for some automatic variable storing all options given, but I could not find it.

I ask because I want the build process to be slightly different depending on whether or not `-j` was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a standard practice (or a good advise), but here it is:

**makefile:**

```
something:
    @echo MAKEFLAGS : $(MAKEFLAGS)
```

**Running:**

```
/home/user> make something
MAKEFLAGS :

/home/user> make -j  something
MAKEFLAGS : -j

/home/user> make -j 10  something
MAKEFLAGS : -j10 --jobserver-auth=3,4

/home/user> make -j20  something
MAKEFLAGS : -j20 --jobserver-auth=3,4
```

Comment: Note that only in GNU make 4.2 and above will you see the amount of parallelism listed; in previous versions it will just say `-j` no matter what you specify.  However for the question that's sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `MAKEFLAGS` GNU make variable.

```
echo 'all:;: $(MAKEFLAGS)' | make -f-
: 

echo 'all:;: $(MAKEFLAGS)' | make -f- -j
:  -j
```